# Verify email from the admin not from the users in firebase web using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

1) When user submitted signup form, instead verification email send to the user it should be sent to the admin for the verification 
2) OR the email verification to be done by some code generated by the admin to provide access.
3)OR Is there any way to disable firebase email accounts by default?
Please Help?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. On one hand you want to verify emails from the admin sdk but then you want to disable email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Referring you to :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

From the official documentation should handle your cases